# Pi3 Interface to IR Sensor stays High

Tags: sensor, motion

[image][image]I am new to RPi and trying to trigger a camera with a motion detector.  The motion detector reads High (1) all the time, so pictures are taken continuously.  I had the IR detector working with an LED before I moved on to this, so I am pretty sure it should work.  I am including some code and my breadboard setup.  Would appreciate advice.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import picamera,time
import datetime
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


pir_sensor = 11

pygame.init()
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.iso = 800

INITIALSLEEP = 10
PICSLEEP = 3
picpath = '/home/pi/Pictures/ggIRPics/'

def uniquename(extstring):
    translation = {ord(":"): None, ord(";"): None, ord("-"): None, ord("  "): None, ord("."): None}
    dt = picpath + 'Pic' + str(datetime.datetime.now())
    tempstr = dt.translate(translation)+extstring
    return tempstr

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(pir_sensor, GPIO.IN)

current_state = 0


try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        current_state = GPIO.input(pir_sensor)
        print('GPIO pin %s is %s' % (pir_sensor, current_state))
        if current_state == 1:
            print('GPIO pin %s is %s' % (pir_sensor, current_state))
            #camera.start_preview()
            camera.capture(uniquename('.jpg'))
            #camera.stop_preview()
            #time.sleep(PICSLEEP)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Are you sure the pin state is 1 all the time? in your `try except` code block the statement to capture a picture is not indented with `current_state==1` so regardless of what the state of the pin is, it will take a picture.

Comment: Thanks. Good catch but that is a mistake in the post. The actual code is all indented properly under the if statement.  The print statement before the if and the one after the if always return a 1. I corrected the code above to reflect the problem.

Comment: What was the IR led sensor project that was working before, is it online?

Comment: https://diyhacking.com/raspberry-pi-gpio-control/

Comment: Ok, a few things to check, I can't see exactly where your wires are going to but I'm assuming yellow red black going up in the picture is the IR sensor. So first question: Is the ground rail on that side (the one connected to the black wire) connected to a ground? I see ground connected on the right side of the board, not the left (note: right and left ground rails are not connected). That might send the full 5v down the yellow wire. Question 2, what is the resistor for? is it required by the IR sensor? Because its not attached to a LED now. Third question, is the sensor rated for 5v or 3.3v?

Comment: In fact, not only are right and left ground rails not connected, look at the left side of your board. you see the break in the blue line running down the left side? That's a break in the ground wire too. There are actually 4 power quadrants on your breadboard. Each one is isolated. I think the problem is your IR sensor is not connected to ground.

Comment: Thanks.  I simplified the code and wiring and the same problem occurs.  I changed to photo in this post to reflect the new wiring.  It is a 4v IR sensor, and the code is picking up a signal, so  I am sure the power is working and the yellow wire as well.  the new code is as follows: 
    from gpiozero import MotionSensor
    import time

    pir = MotionSensor(4)
    time.sleep(5)
    while True:
        if pir.motion_detected:
            print("Motion detected")
            time.sleep(1)

Comment: This just prints "motion detected" over and over
Sorry - the code doesn't format well in the comment??

Answer (score 0):

I found a tutorial that answered all the issues.  The wiring is simple but the problem was probably in the timeout potentiometer.  Many tutorials mention the potentiometers, but this is the first I found that specified the actual range of values.  Once triggered, the On signal can last as long as 250 seconds, depending on the setting.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/physical-computing-with-python/pir/

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.